# Populate a listview with different objects/items

Tags: listview, nativescript

In Nativescript Listview, is it possible to have a listview populated with more than one type of object - each object having it's own separate layout.

If not in the built-in ListView, how about the telerik RadListView - will that do it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I do not think there is a clear built-in way of doing different templates, for example grouping is not available in both ListView and RadListView (this feature is still under consideration in RadListView). You could go ahead and try to implement it yourself but it will not be pretty. You could do something like this:

- Create your 'business data' object that will represent your 'item' and create an indicator property that will show which visual (template) should be used
- After that declare your template in either the ListView or RadListView that contains X different 'layouts' one of which will be hidden (by its Visibility).
- Depending on the property of of the 'business data' object toggle the Visibility of the X layouts which are your custom templates.

This is the basic idea of how you can go on achieving such "multiple different templates", of course there are other approaches that could be used. On a side note make sure that initially all of the layouts are 'hidden' to achieve the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

RadListView now offers this functionality of multiple item templates. See [RadListView: Item template/templates: Using multiple item templates](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/multiple-templates#using-multiple-item-templates).

Looks like this:

```
<lv:RadListView items="{{ dataItems }}" itemTemplateSelector="{{ templateSelector }}">

    <lv:RadListView.itemTemplates>
        <template key="template1">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                ...
            </StackLayout>
        </template>
        <template key="template2">
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                ...
            </StackLayout>
        </template>
    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplates>

</lv:RadListView>
```